# Event of multiple checkboxes using onCheckedChanged

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a problem with login checkboxes

First, I`m going to make 3 checkboxes and created change listener for each

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private CheckBox main_id_saver;
private CheckBox main_pw_saver;
private CheckBox main_auto_login;
```

and allocate ID of wigets for each too in onCreate(xml file is skipped)

```
main_id_saver = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.main_id_saver);
main_pw_saver = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.main_pw_saver);
main_auto_login = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.main_auto_login);

main_id_saver.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
main_pw_saver.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
main_auto_login.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

and I want to set a click event for checkboxes which satisfies below

1. If ID, PW checkboxes is checked, then auto login checkboxes are checked automatically
2. cannot check PW checkbox only
3. If auto login is checked, then ID, PW are checked automatically
4. If any checkbox is clicked in status of all checkboxes are checked, then all checkboxes are unchecked

I made some tries and below is that

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (main_auto_login.isChecked()){
        if(!main_id_saver.isChecked() || !main_pw_saver.isChecked()) {
            main_id_saver.setChecked(true);
            main_pw_saver.setChecked(true);
            return;
        } else if (main_id_saver.isChecked()&&main_pw_saver.isChecked()&&main_auto_login.isChecked()){
            main_auto_login.setChecked(false);
            main_id_saver.setChecked(false);
            main_pw_saver.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }
    } else if(main_pw_saver.isChecked()){
        if(main_id_saver.isChecked()){
            main_auto_login.setChecked(true);
            return;
        } else if(!main_id_saver.isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CANNOT REMEMBER PASSWORD BUT FOR ID",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            main_pw_saver.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

but it doesn`t work as I have thought

what is the best code for this problem?

In my arrogant opinion, making onChangedLinster event separately is the best answer but I cannot make it...

Comment: where is `onCheckedChanged` of remaining 2 checkboxes

Comment: Try setting an instance field like `dontFire = false;` and then in the event
`if(dontFire) return;
dontFire = true;
.
.
dontFire = false;`
When you call `setChecked` the event is called again and I guess this messes things up.

Comment: @Redman is it onCheckedChanged is applied for all checkbox changing?

Comment: @alfoks setting boolean type variable is the only way to deal with this? ok thank you sir

Comment: @timedeveloper that's how I handle calling `setChecked` inside the event itself. See the answer of Ekrem for simplifying your code, but still you'll need to stop the event being called again.

Comment: @alfoks ah yeah I got what you mean sir. That setChecked function recalls sanother setChecked again and again. Seems like smart compiler has stopped this horrible loop for newbie coder...

Answer (score 4):

```
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            switch (buttonView.getId()){
                case R.id.checkbox1:
                    if(isChecked)
                        //Do something
                    else
                        //Do something
                    break;
                case R.id.checkBox2:
                    if(isChecked)
                    //Do something
                    else
                    //Do something
                    break;


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ah, that`s what I wanted. Thank you sir

Comment: What's `chk`? Is it some sort of grouping component?

Comment: chk is CheckBox.